# Selenium testing - click to expand a jstree node

Tags: selenium, junit, jstree

I'm trying to write some selenium tests for a java app with a jsp page using jstree.  I haven't done much of this although I have quite a few basic tests to follow.

Essentially the id's are auto generated so I'm using xpath to locate specific points of interest.  On the page the leaf I am hoping to select is hidden (and so not available for testing).  Thus the first task in my unit test is to expand a specific link and so the child nodes are rendered and available for my actual tests.  The element which seems to hold the key to this is an i tag.

EDIT for clarity

---

If you look at https://www.jstree.com/demo/ I'm essentially trying to get to the Building node under LED in a java selenium test (so if you look at source when you open the page there is no reference to Building, but when you open the LED node the html is rendered).  I hope this makes sense?!

---

```
 <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="M[randomnumber]_anchor" aria-expanded="false" id=" M[randomnumber]" class="jstree-node treeNodeTextParentLevel3 jstree-closed">    
  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id=" M[randomnumber]_anchor ">
      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i>
      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>
     Visible leaf text</a>
  </li>
```

Using Chrome Developer tools tells me that

```
<i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
```

is the element you need to click to expand the child nodes.

This sets

```
aria-expanded="true"
```

and

```
class="jstree-node jstree-open"
```

So I have used 2 approaches to this

1) If I try

```
 driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
          By.xpath("//aside/div/div/ul/li[@id=’knownId] ']/ul/li[contains(@id,'M')]/i"))).click();
```

I get an error

```
Element <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i> is
> not clickable at point
```

Which possibly seems fair for an i tag ?

2) So I tried to do it directly through altering the attributes

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//aside/div/div/ul/li[@id=’knownId']/ul/li[contains(@id,'M')]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-expanded',arguments[1]);", element, "true");
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('class',arguments[1]);", element, "jstree-node jstree-open");
```

but in this case the tree leaf is not expanded (although if I do a element.getAttribute("aria-expanded"); afterwards for example the attribute has been updated it seems to do nothing on the page being tested) and so I cannot select the child item I actually want to test.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please ?

Comment: can you share the site url ?

Comment: sorry it's not live yet but if you look at https://www.jstree.com/demo/ I'm essentially trying to get to the Building node under LED in a java selenium test (so if you look at source when you open the page there is no reference to Building, but when you open the LED node the html is rendered).  Actually I'll add this as a note in the question so as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried same on given site

Here `JavascriptExecutor` is working for click on to the element

I have tried below code :

```
// tree menu present under iframe so need to switch into iframe first
driver.switchTo().frame(0);

// used to click on expand option of LED
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LED']/i"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);


 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("LED/Building_anchor")).getText());
```

Other Example could be  if you want to click on `Test` under LED > Building >Test

Then you can try like

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// To click on expand menu of LED
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LED']/i")));

// To click on expand menu of Building     
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LED/Building']/i")));

// To click on TestFile under building      
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.id("LED/Building/Test_anchor")));
```

You can try like this in your application. Please let me know if any thing

Comment: Thanks that's great.  I should probably look at the JavascriptExecutor a bit more!  Really useful.